# SAS loop through datasets

Tags: sas

I have multiple tables in a library call snap1:

cust1, cust2, cust3, etc

I want to generate a loop that gets the records' count of the same column in each of these tables and then insert the results into a different table.

My desired output is:

```
Table Count

cust1 5,000
cust2 5,555
cust3 6,000
```

I'm trying this but its not working:

```
%macro sqlloop(data, byvar);
proc sql noprint;
select &byvar.into:_values SEPARATED by '_'
from %data.;
quit;
data_&values.;
set &data;
select (%byvar);

%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(count(_&_values.,_));
%let var = %sysfunc(scan(_&_values.,&i.));
output &var.;
%end;
end;

run;
%mend;

%sqlloop(data=libsnap, byvar=membername);
```

Comment: Can you explain better what you want?  Example input and output would help.  Before trying to create a macro make sure that you know how write the code for one specific case. Then you can begin to write a macro that generates that code for other cases.  Right now your macro is not generating any valid SAS code.

Comment: What does that code have to do with your result?  It's not going to do anything at all remotely related to what you're saying you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *** Updated ***

In the future, please post the log so we can see what is specifically not working. I can see some issues in your code, particularly where your macro variables are being declared, and a `select` statement that is not doing anything. Here is an alternative process to achieve your goal:

**Step 1:** Read all of the customer datasets in the `snap1` library into a macro variable:

```
proc sql noprint;
    select memname
    into :total_cust separated by ' '
    from sashelp.vmember
    where upcase(memname) LIKE 'CUST%'
          AND upcase(libname) = 'SNAP1';
quit;
```

**Step 2:** Count the total number of obs in each data set, output to permanent table:

```
 %macro count_obs;
      %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&total_cust) );
           %let dsname = %scan(&total_cust, &i);

           %let dsid=%sysfunc(open(&dsname) );
           %let nobs=%sysfunc(attrn(&dsid,nobs) );
           %let rc=%sysfunc(close(&dsid) );

           data _total_obs;
                length Member_Name $15.;
                Member_Name = "&dsname";
                Total_Obs = &nobs;

                format Total_Obs comma8.; 
           run;

           proc append base=Total_Obs
                       data=_total_obs;
           run;
     %end;

     proc datasets lib=work nolist;
         delete _total_obs;
     quit;

 %mend;
 %count_obs;
```

You will need to delete the permanent table `Total_Obs` if it already exists, but you can add code to handle that if you wish.

If you want to get the total number of non-missing observations for a particular column, do the same code as above, but delete the 3 `%let` statements below `%let dsname =` and replace the `data` step with:

```
data _total_obs;
     length Member_Name $7.;
     set snap1.&dsname end=eof;
     retain Member_Name "&dsname";

     if(NOT missing(var) ) then Total_Obs+1;

     if(eof);

     format Total_Obs comma8.;
run;
```

---

(Update: Fixed %do loop in step 2)

Comment: This works but the names of the tables are not exactly cust1, cust2, etc. How do i get the code print the exact names?

Comment: Updated with a more generalized solution

Comment: If you're just getting number of obs from the dataset headers, why not just query dictionary.tables?

Comment: That's a perfectly viable solution as well. The only reason why I did not do that is because I have been in situations where the amount of autoassigned libraries and their respective columns from the metadata server made querying sashelp.vtable an extremely slow process, whereas sashelp.vmember tended to be more manageable.

Answer (score 3):

First off, if you just want the number of observations, you can get that trivially from `dictionary.tables` or `sashelp.vtable` without any loops.

```
proc sql;
  select memname, nlobs
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname='SNAP1';
quit;
```

This is fine to retrieve number of rows if you haven't done anything that would cause the number of logical observations to differ - usually a delete in proc sql.

Second, if you're interested in the number of valid responses, there are easier non-loopy ways too.

For example, given whatever query that you can write determining your table names, we can just put them all in a `set` statement and count in a simple data step.

```
%let varname=mycol; *the column you are counting;
%let libname=snap1;


proc sql;
  select cats("&libname..",memname) 
    into :tables separated by ' '
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname=upcase("&libname.");
quit;

data counts;
  set &tables. indsname=ds_name end=eof; *9.3 or later;
  retain count dataset_name;
  if _n_=1 then count=0;
  if ds_name ne lag(ds_name) and _n_ ne 1 then do;
    output;
    count=0;
  end;
  dataset_name=ds_name;
  count = count + ifn(&varname.,1,1,0);  *true, false, missing;  *false is 0 only;
  if eof then output;
  keep count dataset_name;
run;
```

Macros are rarely needed for this sort of thing, and macro loops like you're writing even less so.

If you did want to write a macro, the easier way to do it is:

- Write code to do it once, for one dataset
- Wrap that in a macro that takes a parameter (dataset name)
- Create macro calls for that macro as needed

That way you don't have to deal with `%scan` and troubleshooting macro code that's hard to debug.  You write something that works once, then just call it several times.

```
proc sql;
  select cats('%mymacro(name=',"&libname..",memname,')') 
    into :macrocalls separated by ' '
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname=upcase("&libname.");
quit;

&macrocalls.;
```

Assuming you have a macro, `%mymacro`, which does whatever counting you want for one dataset.

Comment: Code is untested until tomorrow morning, will make any fixes then.

Comment: can i apply a filter here to the statement below? so most of the tables in library snap1 have a column with date, I just wanna count the records with the latest date.    I tried adding a simple where date eq max(date) but it's not working.                                                                              proc sql;
  select memname, nlrows
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname='SNAP1';
quit;

Comment: @CA_CA You can't use the first query if you're trying to filter by something in the dataset. If you're looking at most recent modified date, that's fine.  That's only using the metadata, though.  You'd need something that let you look at the datasets themselves (like the second half of my answer) to do something conditional on the data inside the dataset.