# The SAS way to loop over a table outside a data step

Tags: loops, sas, sas-macro

I am wondering what is the cleanest way how to perform a macro loop over a data table *outside* a data step in order to e.g. read in files from the table `have` and do some complex analysis for each of the files.

Assume we have a table `have` containing a set of file names and other meta data:

```
N  filename  purpose
1  foo.xls   Blue team data
2  bar.xls   Read team data
```

I was thinking of something like

```
%local lines current_file current_purpose;

proc sql noprint;
   select count(*) into: lines from have;
quit;

%do I=1 %to &lines.;
   %put --- Process file number &I. ---;
   data _null_;
      set have;
      if _n_=&I. then do;
        call symput('current_file',filename);
        call symput('current_purpose',purpose);
      end;
   run;
   %put --- &current_file. contains &purpose.;
   /* Here comes the actual analysis */ 
%end;
```

Is this the way how to do it? For me, this does not look like the simplest way.

#### Related questions:

- [SAS loop through datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638620/sas-loop-through-datasets)
- [SAS let statement: refer to a cell value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089896/)

Comment: https://github.com/statgeek/SAS-Tutorials/blob/master/Turning%20a%20program%20into%20a%20macro.md

Comment: @Reeza: What is that github-link about? Looks like a cool introduction to macro-based thinking. If you intend to tell me that I should always have that in my mind: My job is usually to maintain the code of others with the paradigm of minimal modifications...

Comment: I 'intended' to provide a fully worked example of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if you defined a macro name ANALYSIS with input parameters FILENAME and PURPOSE.

```
%macro analysis(filename,purpose);
  /* Here comes the actual analysis */ 
  title &purpose ;
  proc import datafile="&filename" ....
%mend;
```

Then you can use a data step to generate one call to the macro for each observation. You can use CALL EXECUTE, but I find it clearer and easier to debug to just write the code to a file and then %INCLUDE it. Especially when the parameter name matches the variable name in the metadata being used to drive the code generation.

So this step :

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
   set have;
   file code;
   put '%analysis(' filename= ',' purpose= :$quote. ')' ;
run;
```

Will generate a program like:

```
%analysis(filename=foo.xls,purpose="Blue team data")
%analysis(filename=bar.xls,purpose="Red team data")
```

Which you can then run using

```
%include code / source2;
```

Comment: The idea is clever, and in the current case I might actually have the rare freedom to change the architecture along what you suggested.